# Openstack All-In-One Single Machine Networking

Tags: openstack

I'm having a hard time configuring an Openstack environment based on the All-In-One Single Machine installer for bridged networking in my LAN.

My objective is to SSH into the instances created in Openstack from my LAN.

The server is an Ubuntu 16.04 LTS with minimal installation and OpenSSH. The network configuration of the server is:

```html
auto enp3s0
iface enp3s0 inet static
address 10.4.4.1
netmask 255.255.255.0
gateway 10.4.4.254
broadcast 10.4.4.255
network 10.4.4.0
dns-nameservers 10.4.1.12 10.4.1.10
```

Basically my network details are the following:

```html
LAN 10.4.4.0
MASK 255.255.255.0
Gateway/DHCP Server  10.4.4.254
```

The local.conf file I've used for deploying the devstack is the following:

```html
# Sample ``local.conf`` for user-configurable variables in ``stack.sh``

# NOTE: Copy this file to the root DevStack directory for it to work properly.

# ``local.conf`` is a user-maintained settings file that is sourced from ``stackrc``.
# This gives it the ability to override any variables set in ``stackrc``.
# Also, most of the settings in ``stack.sh`` are written to only be set if no
# value has already been set; this lets ``local.conf`` effectively override the
# default values.

# This is a collection of some of the settings we have found to be useful
# in our DevStack development environments. Additional settings are described
# in https://docs.openstack.org/devstack/latest/configuration.html#local-conf
# These should be considered as samples and are unsupported DevStack code.

# The ``localrc`` section replaces the old ``localrc`` configuration file.
# Note that if ``localrc`` is present it will be used in favor of this section.
[[local|localrc]]

# Minimal Contents
# ----------------

# While ``stack.sh`` is happy to run without ``localrc``, devlife is better when
# there are a few minimal variables set:

# If the ``*_PASSWORD`` variables are not set here you will be prompted to enter
# values for them by ``stack.sh``and they will be added to ``local.conf``.
FLOATING_RANGE=10.4.4.192/27
FIXED_RANGE=192.168.0.0/24
FIXED_NETWORK_SIZE=256
FLAT_INTERFACE=enp3s0
ADMIN_PASSWORD=nomoresecret
DATABASE_PASSWORD=stackdb
RABBIT_PASSWORD=stackqueue
SERVICE_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

# ``HOST_IP`` and ``HOST_IPV6`` should be set manually for best results if
# the NIC configuration of the host is unusual, i.e. ``eth1`` has the default
# route but ``eth0`` is the public interface.  They are auto-detected in
# ``stack.sh`` but often is indeterminate on later runs due to the IP moving
# from an Ethernet interface to a bridge on the host. Setting it here also
# makes it available for ``openrc`` to include when setting ``OS_AUTH_URL``.
# Neither is set by default.
HOST_IP=10.4.4.1
#HOST_IPV6=2001:db8::7


# Logging
# -------

# By default ``stack.sh`` output only goes to the terminal where it runs.  It can
# be configured to additionally log to a file by setting ``LOGFILE`` to the full
# path of the destination log file.  A timestamp will be appended to the given name.
LOGFILE=$DEST/logs/stack.sh.log

# Old log files are automatically removed after 7 days to keep things neat.  Change
# the number of days by setting ``LOGDAYS``.
LOGDAYS=2

# Nova logs will be colorized if ``SYSLOG`` is not set; turn this off by setting
# ``LOG_COLOR`` false.
#LOG_COLOR=False


# Using milestone-proposed branches
# ---------------------------------

# Uncomment these to grab the milestone-proposed branches from the
# repos:
#CINDER_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#GLANCE_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#HORIZON_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#KEYSTONE_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#KEYSTONECLIENT_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#NOVA_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#NOVACLIENT_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#NEUTRON_BRANCH=milestone-proposed
#SWIFT_BRANCH=milestone-proposed

# Using git versions of clients
# -----------------------------
# By default clients are installed from pip.  See LIBS_FROM_GIT in
# stackrc for details on getting clients from specific branches or
# revisions.  e.g.
# LIBS_FROM_GIT="python-ironicclient"
# IRONICCLIENT_BRANCH=refs/changes/44/2.../1

# Swift
# -----

# Swift is now used as the back-end for the S3-like object store. Setting the
# hash value is required and you will be prompted for it if Swift is enabled
# so just set it to something already:
SWIFT_HASH=66a3d6b56c1f479c8b4e70ab5c2000f5

# For development purposes the default of 3 replicas is usually not required.
# Set this to 1 to save some resources:
SWIFT_REPLICAS=1

# The data for Swift is stored by default in (``$DEST/data/swift``),
# or (``$DATA_DIR/swift``) if ``DATA_DIR`` has been set, and can be
# moved by setting ``SWIFT_DATA_DIR``. The directory will be created
# if it does not exist.
SWIFT_DATA_DIR=$DEST/data
```

At the end of the deployment I'm able to ping from the instance to my LAN and do nslookup on google.com for example, but I can't do it backwards, ping/ssh/telnet the instance in Openstack.
The security group permits all traffic, all ICMP ingress/egress, SSH from everywhere.

I've tried to telnet on my local computer from the Openstack instance and it's showing the IP of the Openstack host, not the host. So I'm missing something in the network topology.

```html
netstat -ant | grep 1716
tcp6       0      0 :::1716                 :::*                    LISTEN     
tcp6       0      0 10.4.3.34:1716          10.4.4.1:42992          ESTABLISHED
```

Is there any type of network deployment I'm missing?
Any advice would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access your instances from the "outside", you will need to create a floating IP pool and assign a floating IP to one of your instances.